# H2 Database Run Script First before Creating the Schema

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am trying to use the in-memory database H2 for some testing, In my case I am trying to Create the Schema and load the Schema with some data.

The problem that I am having is when I run a test it tries to run the script first without creating the schema and I get the errror table does not exists.

application-test.yml file

```
spring:

      datasource:
          driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
          url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS sample\;runscript from '~/LoadData.sql'

      jpa:
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: create-drop
        properties:
          hibernate:
            default_schema: sample
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 0
spring:
  application:
    name: services
  devtools:
    livereload:
        enabled: false
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        default_schema: ${APP_DATASOURCE_SCHEMA}
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    hibernate:
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    jackson:
      serialization:
        indent-output: true
logging:
  level:
    com.application: DEBUG
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 3
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 4
sample:
  application:
    portrange:
      min: 8090
      max: 8099
    sendemail: false
ldap:
  contextSource:
    url: ${LDAP_URL}
    base: ${LDAP_BASE}
    userDn: ${LDAP_USER_DN}
    password: ${LDAP_PASSWORD}
```

Comment: please your app and test configuration

Comment: what is your script's filename ?

Comment: Script file name is LoadData.sql